# Create a new portal container using extension for Jboss Portal (JPP-6.1.0)

Tags: jboss, portlet, portal, jboss-portal

We wanted to have multiple portal container with JPP6 using deployable ear file. From the JPP6 documentation its clear that one can have more then one (multiple) portlet container and each container can have multiple website.

Is there any reference project to create/lunch portal container and website with specific user access permission e.g. http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/jpp-quickstarts/gatein-sample-portal/ OR https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateANewPortalContainerUsingExtension

The above mentioned projects are not compatible or working with JPP6.

Any reference for JPP6 would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a single instance (or cluster) of JBoss Portal, multiple portals can be running and share resources with other portals with two levels of granularity. i.e. Jboss portal instance can host muktiple portal containers each can allow to host multiple site. An maven project can be created and deployed on GateIn container to add another instance of portal container. a sample project can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-portal-quickstarts/tree/master/gatein-sample-portal)